# Grouping data by sklearn.model_selection.GroupShuffleSplit

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a dataset in a CSV with header as

```
PRODUCT_ID  CATEGORY_NAME   PRODUCT_TYPE DISPLAY_COLOR_NAME IMAGE_ID
```

with same product having multiple rows each with different `image_id`.  I made Image Id as index col when reading CSV into pandas data frame.

I want to create test and train dataset by grouping the data at `product_type` or any other column.  Also make sure same data is not repeated in both test and train dataset (since I have multiple lines for product with different images)

How can I achieve this using `sklearn.model_selection.GroupShuffleSplit`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I came up with, would like to see if this can be better done

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupShuffleSplit

data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('/myfileLocation/PRODUCTS.csv', index_col='IMAGE_ID')
data.reset_index()['PRODUCT_ID']
gss = GroupShuffleSplit(n_splits=1, test_size=0.3)
train_dataset,test_dataset = next(gss.split(X=data, y=data['PRODUCT_TYPE_NAME'], groups=data.index.values))

for x in np.nditer(test_dataset.T):
    rec = data.iloc[x]
    print (rec)
```

Comment: If this is part of the question, you should edit your question instead of posting this as an answer. If you have working code and only want feedback on improvements, you should post on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: It is working code, I wanted to share it because I could not find an example for the problem that I was searching for. At the same time I want to get feedback.  Thank you for suggesting codereview.stackexchange.com will post some code for review in there.